# SAS proc sql find min/max only among missing/non-missing within group

Tags: sql, sas

I have multiple dates per `IID` and I'm looking to find the max (maybe min down the road) within the group **only** if another variable is missing. Take the following test data:

```
data test;
    informat EFF_DATE END_DATE date9.;
    length IID $12 EFF_DATE END_DATE 8;
    input IID $ EFF_DATE END_DATE;
    format EFF_DATE END_DATE date9.;
    datalines;
    A   11MAY15 .   
    A   12SEP13 01JAN15
    A   13DEC12 .
    B   25AUG14 .   
    B   13JUN17 01JAN15
    B   03NOV13 .
    ;
run;
```

My plan is to build off the following code to calculate the max `EFF_DATE` by `IID`, but only if `END_DATE` is missing which I cannot figure out how to add this logic in `sql`.

```
proc sql noprint;
    create table test_fill as
    select *,
        max(EFF_DATE) /* add something here? */ as MOST_RECENT_EFF_DATE format=date9.
    from test group by IID;
quit;
```

The following shows the desired output:

```
IID EFF_DATE    END_DATE    MOST_RECENT_EFF_DATE
A   11MAY15     .           11MAY15
A   12SEP13     01JAN15     11MAY15
A   13DEC12     .           11MAY15
B   25AUG14     .           25AUG14
B   13JUN17     01JAN15     25AUG14
B   03NOV13     .           25AUG14
```

For IID=B, even though 13JUN17 is the max date we cannot accept it because END_DATE is non-missing so I need to take the next highest date. I'm sure I could write a bunch of data steps and merge back but I'd like to try to knock it out in `sql` if possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You include the condition as a `case` inside the `max` function, with `else` being null (which is not `max` ever, nor is it `min`).

```
proc sql noprint;
    create table test_fill as
    select *,
        max(case when missing(end_Date) then EFF_DATE else . end) as MOST_RECENT_EFF_DATE format=date9.
    from test group by IID;
quit;
```

Comment: Thanks @Joe -- exactly what I'm looking for. The nested `case when` statements will be useful for all my logic moving forward!